# Partition cloning using dd and a compression tool

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, compression

Following the  [catastrophe](https://superuser.com/questions/1746253/windows-10-blue-screen-of-death-on-startup-after-running-faulty-cleanup-script) that happened with me recently, I decided to start making backups to my data. I was searching for best ways to clone partitions and disks and came across a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning)  on another site on the stackexchange network.

The second answer seems interesting however in the second part, it suggests the following:

> To save even more space, defragment the drive/partition you wish to clone beforehand (if appropriate), then zero-out all the remaining unused space, making it easier for gzip to compress

This seems to be time consuming process and it could reduce the life span of a HDD, so I was thinking: why zero-out the unused space of the hard drive? why not shrink the partition to near the size it occupies on the disk and then use dd in conjunction with gzip?

For example, if the partition hosting my Windows installation is 450GB in size and the size of the used data is 80GB, I could use "Disk Management" on Windows to shrink the partition by '450 - 80 + 0.5'GB. The 0.5GB is to avoid problems with background processes trying to write to disk.

I can then use live linux distro to execute the command:

```
dd if=/dev/hdb | gzip -c  > /image.img.gz
```

I can then go back to windows and extend the partition to claim the unallocated space.

Since I haven't tried this approach, I want to ask:

Am I missing something / is there anything wrong with it?

The reason am asking is I haven't found a single answer or article mention this approach.

My second question is: Is there nowadays better compression tool than gzip for this purpose?

Comment: Just buy more space. Hard drives are cheap these days.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I actually have ssd not hdd. what I meant to say there is hard drive which can be used for an ssd, right? Also Windows backup tool doesn't allow to save image to usb

Comment: Windows 7 backup restore certainly supports writing to USB and I am reading that the "newer one" (and worse if you ask me) also supports this.  Windows 10 still has the windows 7 version because it does things the other one wont.  They try to hide it but it is still there.  People will cry "It's deprecated!! Don't use it!" but it is still in use at Microsoft itself and it's product (a VHD file) will be supported for many years to come as Microsoft supports this as a mountable file system.

Comment: And even if you wanted to defrag that SSD, very few tools will let you as there is no point and it will wear out the drive (you are correct .. which you know).

Comment: As for better tools for compression: `zstd` has impressive performance _and_ compression ratio.

Comment: If this is SSD, then the free space is likely zeroed at some point, thanks to the trim+garbage collection mechanism. So no need to explicitely fill the free space with zero or to shrink the partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems to be time consuming process and it could reduce the life span of a HDD, so I was thinking: why zero-out the unused space of the hard drive? why not shrink the partition to near the size it occupies on the disk and then use dd in conjunction with gunzip?

Shrinking the partition is *also* a time-consuming process, as it needs to move a large amount of data – which is typically spread out across the entire partition (to avoid fragmentation) rather than all files being packed at the beginning, so the more you want to shrink a partition the more data needs to be physically moved to a different place.

Above a certain "used" percentage, it may even be slower than zeroing out empty space, as the shrink tool needs to *read* data before writing it elsewhere, working at less than half the speed of the HDD as a result.

(Also, often Windows will refuse to shrink an online filesystem beyond a certain point – e.g. if you start with a ~1TB filesystem often the minimum will be ~450GB even though the filesystem is near-empty. An offline shrink from Windows PE, or even from Linux using ntfsresize, may be needed to reduce it further.)

Two much better options are:

1. Clone the partition using `ntfsclone`, which behaves like `dd` except it understands the NTFS space allocation bitmap, so it will avoid reading any sectors that NTFS considers unused. The result is similar to pre-zeroing a filesystem but *much* faster, as the empty sectors are neither written to nor read from.

   `partclone` is a similar tool that supports more filesystems, but unfortunately can only output its proprietary image format (which needs a second partclone invocation for restoring back to a physical partition), whereas ntfsclone just outputs a "raw" image which can be written directly to the new partition.

   In some situations you can use `Disk2vhd.exe`, which runs on Windows and always outputs a VHD or VHDX image file (it is meant for converting physical Windows installations to Hyper-V). The VHD(X) images are dynamically-allocated, so they only occupy as much space as needed – and they can be attached as virtual disks on any Windows 10 system. However, Disk2vhd does not have a companion tool for restoring *from* VHD to a physical disk (though this could be done using qemu-img).
2. Create a file-level image using `dism.exe /capture-image`, which outputs a WIM archive (the same type as the Windows installation process uses) – which can then be extracted to a fresh NTFS partition using `/apply-image`, preserving [nearly] all of the Windows-specific metadata.

   You can do this from Windows PE, e.g. by booting up the Windows installer or a recovery environment then hitting Shift+F10 for the Command Prompt.

   This method avoids any resize-related problems (e.g. you can capture an image from a 1TB disk and extract it to a 256GB one), but it's slower than ntfsclone since you need an intermediate place to store the image, and it's unclear whether it actually captures *all* metadata. (For example, it turns out that you need to use the `/EA` option in order to include extended attributes used by WSL1.)

Comment: My hard drive is PCIe Gen3 x4 NVMe SSD. When I shrank the partition by 100GB for Windows 10, it took ~2 seconds.